# How to make a SSH to postgres server with help of ssh2 library and query using pg libary?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssh

I am trying to make a connection to Postgres remote host using the SSH tunnel from node application(library:ssh2) and query the data(lib:pg).

Before I used mysql2(node library) make a tunnel using ssh2(node library) and connected to Mysql remote host as well as able to query the data. But I want to do the same in Postgres remote host I am not able to connect to it.

pg Client obj config does not support the stream from ssh2 forwardOut..!

Or, Is there any library available to make this happen instead of that ssh2, pg

PS: In mysql2 when I try to make a connection with a mysql config with stream: stream key value.

```
var Clientssh = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Clientssh();
conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.forwardOut(
        '127.0.0.1',
        5434,
        'localhost',
        5432,
        function(err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let conf = {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 5434,
                user: 'test',
                database: 'test',
                password: 'test'
            }
            let remoteConnection = new Client(conf);
            remoteConnection.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Unable to connect to postgre");
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    remoteConnection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(err, testResult) {
                        remoteConnection.end();
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Unable to fetch data");
                            res.send(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Succcess");
                            res.send(testResult);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
}).connect({
    host: 'hostaddress',
    port: 'hostport',
    username: 'hostusername',
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('path/for/key')
});
```

It shows the Connection terminated unexpectedly from this line

```
Client :: ready
Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
    at Connection.con.once (/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:235:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Channel.<anonymous> (/node-postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:131:10)
    at Channel.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Unable to connect to postgre
```

Comment: `stream` is an available config option with the `pg` module, but only if you use its pure js client instead of its native client.