# Connect to postgres database via ssh from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssh

I am always getting connection refused error,
[image]

while if I connect via dbeaver its get successful. Please help me with what am I missing here.
I have tried via tunnel-ssh, pg. Still same issue.

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
const postgres = require("postgres");
// SSH Configuration
const sshConfig = {
  host: '143.xx.xxx.xx',
  port: 22,
  username: 'root',
  password:"*****"
};

// PostgreSQL Database Configuration
const dbConfig = {
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost', // This is localhost because we're using an SSH tunnel
  database: 'postgres',
  password: '******',
  port: 30432, // PostgreSQL port on the remote server
};

// Create an SSH tunnel
const sshTunnel = new Client();
async function getUsersOver(sql) {
  const users = await sql`
    select
      *
    from users
  `
  // users = Result [{ name: "Walter", age: 80 }, { name: 'Murray', age: 68 }, ...]
  return users
}
sshTunnel.on('ready', () => {
  sshTunnel.forwardOut(
    'localhost', // Local address
    dbConfig.port, // Local port (automatically assigned)
    dbConfig.host, // Remote address (the database host)
    dbConfig.port, // Remote port (the PostgreSQL port on the remote server)
    (err, stream) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      // Create a PostgreSQL client connected through the SSH tunnel
      const dbClient =  postgres({...dbConfig, stream});
      getUsersOver(dbClient)
    }
  );
});

sshTunnel.connect(sshConfig);
```

Comment: Add the error message that you are getting

Comment: @PepeNO Have added the error screenshot.

Comment: Try establishing manually the ssh tunneling as can be seen in this question to troubleshoot the possible cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835761/postgresql-via-ssh-tunnel?rq=2

Comment: Yes, I tried via dbeaver and its working from there. I am missing something here, I dont know what.
@PepeNO

Comment: Did you use the options in SSH tab of Connection Settings ticking Use SSH Tunnel and filling all the corresponding fields and testing connection successfully?

Comment: "Local port (automatically assigned"  If the local port is automatically assigned, then why are you assigning it?  Could you shared where this code was adapted from (a link to the docs or tutorial or whatever)?

Comment: @jjanes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106900/how-to-make-a-ssh-to-postgres-server-with-help-of-ssh2-library-and-query-using-p

Comment: @PepeNO Yes, I have

Comment: What happended when you did "try establishing manually the ssh tunneling"?

Comment: Since the link you gave is a question with no answer,  I certainly wouldn't take that as a lesson in the correct way to do it.